# Network engineers - What are some specific layer 2 network problems you have seen?

Tags: cisco, vlan, ethernet, switching, best-practices

The networking industry has come to a general consensus that large layer 2 networks are more troublesome to build and maintain because of the inherent problems in the layer 2 switching. To name a few of the main pain points..

- packet loop causing network meltdown
- STP reducing the effective bandwidth of the network
- Because of STP inefficient packet paths in large l2 networks
- Lack of proper ECMP (TRILL came in too late and still not available widely)
- Lack of visibility into the packet path for debugging.
- bandaids like BPDU filter, BPDU guard, port fast etc. making config more difficult and error prone.

I am curious to know what are some real world examples of these kind of issues Network engineers have seen over the years.

If large L2 domains are such a cause of misery why haven't we moved to a model where L2 is terminated at access/TOR switch and reduce the size of L2 domain as much as possible ?

Comment: Hi there. This is a great question, but it's more of a poll rather than a question that's meant to have a single "accepted" answer. This is why you've received two close votes (in case you were wondering).

Comment: Please consider asking a question in [meta] about revising the question to be more suitable for the site

Comment: Have a look at page 49 on this PDF and page 50 onwards for the results: http://goo.gl/uXEw5B

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, that's what people do. But in general, your list is example after example of network admins / engineers doing a poor job. Spanning-tree fixes the first. STP isn't an issue if the network is setup correctly, by someone aware of how STP works.  ECMP is a layer-3 thing; for layer-2, that would be "etherchannel". (eg. LACP) Knowing the packet path is the virtual equivalent of hooking your finger on the wire and following it -- looking on each switch, hop-by-hop. (there's no *traceroute* at layer-2)

Comment: SCP solves the looping issue at the huge cost of wasted bandwidth. By ECMP I meant load balancing the traffic. yes, LACP sort of solves it but only when connecting multiple links between two switches. If you want to load share with more than one switch that tags on one more feature to the mix (Cisco's vPC and the equivalent from other vendors. These 'features' came in late without any standardization making life more difficult for network engineers). My intent though wasn't a l2 vs l3 debate. But to understand some of the real deployment issues seen with large L2 networks.

Comment: I used to say the same thing about STP. Yes, it will cost bandwidth in that it shuts down links, but that's a configuration issue. Using MST or PVST, only select VLANs are blocked on a particular port, preventing a loop, while leaving the link operational for other VLANs. The loss of bandwidth is minimal, and logical loops are prevented.